# Unrecognized argument: --parquet-configurator-implementation

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, sqoop, amazon-emr

Getting error on running below `Sqoop` command:

```sh
sqoop import \
  --connect jdbc:postgresql://172.27.1.14:5432/sqooptest \
  --username postgres --password root1234 \
  --table acko_policy \
  --target-dir s3a://ackodata-sqoop-poc/acko_policy \
  --as-parquetfile \
  --parquet-configurator-implementation hadoop
```

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/aws/redshift/jdbc/redshift-jdbc42-1.2.34.1058.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
20/01/21 09:32:01 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
20/01/21 09:32:01 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
20/01/21 09:32:01 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --parquet-configurator-implementation
20/01/21 09:32:01 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: hadoop
```

Comment: What's version of Sqoop? Please show output of command `sqoop version`

Comment: Please follow the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61731730/7857701 Its the same reason. And also there is nothing called `--parquet-configurator-implementation`